# Oanda API v20 requests failing

Tags: php, rest, curl

I have tried the following code and receive a message saying my particular request is not supported, I cannot find any solutions that are not python for the v20 api. any help would be appreciated on what to use or where im going wrong

My error message is:

> {"errorMessage":"Requested HTTP method is not supported for supplied
>   endpoint."}

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$vars = "price=B&granularity=M5&count=20";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/instruments/EUR_USD/candles");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$vars);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer access-token',
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print  $server_output ;
?>
```

My goal here is to successfully connect and get the response from the endpoint containing data. I have no python experience which is why im trying curl or even a javascript solution would work. Am i just not understanding this API at all?

Answer (score 2):

Two things that stand out in the code are:

- that there is no actual authorisation code. I don’t know if you have removed it for security while posting, or if you don’t realise you need to create a practice account and get an authorisation code for it? Both are free.
- Your code `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` suggests you are trying a POST, whereas a GET is required for the `\instruments` [endpoint](http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live-v20/instrument-ep/).

But the simplest thing I can suggest that might help is to look at the following Github bash script that has taken OANDA's V1 API bash cURL  example, and updated it for the v2 rest API.

https://github.com/p-burke/oanda-REST-v2-API-bash-script

Comment: Thanks, I removed the key for security, and I also used http_get instead of post, had the same issue, turns out I needed the correct endpoint as the one I was using was half structured.